# how to traverse nodes of lxml object to see if an attribute exists?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I using amazon-python-product-api to search for products in amazon.
The search returns a lxml object as below

```
<class 'amazonproduct.processors._lxml.SearchPaginator'>
```

I am interested in getting all the attributes of this `lmxl object` (I am particularly interested
in the attribute `Identifier` if it exists).

I found a couple of post related to this. but not what I am looking for.
Is there a look-up available on `lxml` object to see if an `attribute exists`.

From my reading of `lxml` documentation, there is not one, but I could be totally wrong

Comment: that apparently isn't a standard lxml object - it's part of some third party library. SearchPaginator has a couple of methods to retrieve data, but it's not clear what the format is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with lxml you can use [xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) to search for the attribute like this:

```
lxml.xpath(['//*[@Identifier]'])
```